# Visual Studio 2013 - Variable Value Window In Debugging

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am a newbie programmer, and have Visual Studio Update 3 on my computer. I cannot find the window that displays the values of variables as I am debugging.

I have looked under the pull-down tab at the top entitled "Debug" and "Window", and cannot find anything. I do not know exactly what the window is called either. Please help.

Comment: I think you are looking for "Locals".  I don't remember exactly where it is in the menus, but should at least give you a starting point for finding it.

Comment: You need to have already started debugging, then it will be under Debug->Window. It's Watch or Local, depending what you want to see.

Comment: Try them all.  Press F1 to get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the scoped local variable values or Autos:
you must first have the debugger running, then goto:
DEBUG => Windows => Autos
and
DEBUG => Windows => Locals

to actually see those values, you need to have a debug stopper in place and it get hit by the program.

Alternatively you can - while debugging - highlight a variable name and use the 'Quick Watch'

Answer (score 0):

In the default layout, the `Locals` window will typically be visible in the lower left pane, but *only* while debugging is active.

[image]

Here you can see the debugger windows on the bottom.  The left side shows current breakpoints while the right side is showing watched variables in the pane labeled `Watch 1`.  At the bottom you'll see other panes available to display in the lower left, specifically `Call Stack`, `Command Window`, etc.  The one you want to see all in scope variables at a given breakpoint is `Locals`

If you have closed the locals window, or otherwise cannot find it, there is a way to re-open it through the `Debug->Windows` menu as pnm points out